# Are null and zero articles present in every language, conceptually, or only in English?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

I have been studying Peter Master's [2003 paper](http://escholarship.org/uc/item/2kb4p9r0) regarding null and zero articles and I am still not clear if he is saying that this is a peculiarity of English or if he is saying that this is a conceptual matter and that it will be apparent in all languages.

I ask this particularly as the matter of absent articles is something I meet with in Greek which has no indefinite article and is very generous with the definite. When the Greek article is missing, therefore, it is often quite a significant matter.

Comment: We know it’s more than just English.  I have no idea whether ***all*** languages have it.  It seems reasonable to assume that some language somewhere handles it differently.

Comment: I could invent one that doesn’t...

Comment: @Jim How would you invent one that doesn't ? If it is an underlying concept of all language, I mean.

Comment: I would create a different article that would be used for those cases.

Comment: @Jim I'm interested in the way concepts are visualised and the presence/absence of articles is relevant to this.

Comment: Do you want users to read the entire paper and tell you the "answer"? I.e. Only the English language uses the "null" article (e.g. *I like animals*) or is it a feature of other languages.

Comment: This is a linguistic question, not an English language one, but on EL&U *good* questions are so thin on the ground, we need to clutch onto them.

Comment: Some languages don't have articles/determiners at all. So in those languages, distinguishing between the absence of a definite article and the absence of an indefinite article doesn't make any sense.

Comment: This question would fare better (and get better answers) on Linguistics SE. Can we migrate it there?

Comment: I am trying to grasp the concepts in the mind that require identification to be stated in language. Something exists,  _per se_ , and sometimes that is sufficient to state; sometimes I must 'locate' it with a determiner.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about every language which *isn't* English, not a question about English.

Comment: @PeterTaylor As suggested, I will take it to Linguistics. Many thanks.